# Excel Date Field Conversion Problem

Tags: c#, excel

I currently have an excel sheet with one of the columns being in the date format.

What I see when I open up the spreadsheet is something like 12/29/09 and the program sees 40176.

I figured out this is the value present when I change the column to general text.

My question is **how can I read the value 12/29/09** instead of 40176 or how can I change 40176 into a valid date?

*My program is in c# Must be read in in c#*

---

Here is sample code of my connection if it helps any.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
string myPath = @"C:\Test.xls";
excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = excelApp.Worksheets;
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
 excelApp.Visible = true;

 if(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelApp.Cells[r, 1]).Value2 != null)
     DateString = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelApp.Cells[r, 1]).Value2.ToString();
```

Comment: How are you opening and reading the spreadsheet? Interop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.FromOADate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) to convert the double into a DateTime value.

Comment: Cory and I both owe you a beer:)

Comment: This also works for Visio Dates when you set the field type to visPropTypeDate.

Answer (score 2):

As Reed Copsey said, the `DateTime.FromOADate()` method will convert the value into a `DateTime`. If, however, you want 12/29/09 as a string, and don't want to manipulate it any further, you can use `cell.Text` instead.

Comment: Yep, 4 years later... And u still made my day! :D This should be the answer. people should NOT use "FromOADate()" in this case. U can cast it back to a datetime whenever needed...

Answer (score 1):

Use the excel `TEXT(val,format)` function.

Example:

In cell A2 enter `=today()` and you'll get a number like 40189
if you enter into cell A2

If you enter `=TEXT(today(),"mm/dd/yyyy")` you'll get todays date formatted as text and it will look like `"01/30/2012"`

Answer (score 0):

you could use the **Text** function.

**Syntax**

```
Text(Value,FormatText)
```

**Example**

1)I put the 40176 in a excel A2
2)then i refrence it in the formula below

```
 =TEXT(A2,"mm/dd/yy")
```

on A3

Then the value comes 12/29/09. just like you asked

**Caution:**

If you put single quote instead of double quote it mightn't work